# How can I use ComplexExpand and PowerExpand for Log of complex symbols?

Tags: symbolic, complex

How can I **simplify** Log[ x + I y] or Log[ r Exp[ I phi]
into Log[r] + I Log[ phi]

where r = Abs[x + I y] and Phi = Arg[x + I y]

using ComplexExpand, PowerExpand, etc...

[image: here is some candidate code]
};

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mma.SE.  You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Are your variables all real?  All positive? Etc.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?:

```
FullSimplify[
 ComplexExpand[Log[r Exp[I phi]], TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}], 
 r > 0 && -Pi < phi <= Pi]

(*  I phi + Log[r]  *)
```

You have to do something else to convert `x + I y`.  Something like this, maybe:

```
ComplexExpand[Log[x + I y], TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}]
% /. {Arg[x + I y] -> phi, Abs[x + I y] -> r}
(*
  I Arg[x + I y] + Log[Abs[x + I y]]
  I phi + Log[r]
*)
```